# permutation operator on sequence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, permutations

Let $X$ be a set of sequence of complex number $x=(a_n)$ which vanish as $n\to \infty$ i.e. $a_n\to 0$

now define the permutation operator on it as $Px = \{a_n'\} = \{a_{p(n)}\}$ where $p(n)$ is permutation of $n$

Now I need to show $P$ is linear map from $X\to X$.

The question is if the sequence is finite I know how to show it's linear map take $X$ into itself,how to define permutation for infinite sequence?

Comment: This is not clear.  $X$ is a single sequence, yes?  So what does it mean to speak of a linear map from $X$ to $X$?  And what do you mean by a "permutation"?  For infinite sets there are two things people tend to mean...either a bijection with no restrictions or a bijection that fixes all but finitely many elements.  Which did you mean?

Comment: space $X$ is defined with pointwise addition and scalar multiplication, with sup norm.It seems bijection that fixed all but finite elements are reasonable to be the definition here.thanks.Since only then we can prove that $P$ maps $X$ into $X$

Comment: You say "Let $$ be a sequence of complex number  $X=(a_n)$. "  That's a single sequence.  Perhaps you meant to say "Let $X$ be the vector space of complex sequences which converge to $0$" or something like that?

Comment: In any case:  I'd say the main thing you had to prove was that $P$ actually takes $X$ to itself. That is:   If $A\in X$ is a sequence which converges to $0$, prove that $P(A)$ also converges to $0$.

Comment: @lulu I need to take the permutation definition that fixed all but finitely many elements here coorect?

Comment: It should be easy for you to prove that the map $P$ is linear.  That is, $P(A+B)=P(A)+P(B)$ and $P(\lambda A)=\lambda P(A)$ for $\lambda\in \mathbb C$.

Comment: As to the definition of permutation:  it's easier if you use that definition, but it is true for both definitions.  (and it's not all that difficult even if your permutation is a bijection with no restrictions).

Comment: Yes thanks I got it,easy to prove with $\epsilon-N$

Comment: @lulu ,In fact the limit still zero for any injective map not only bijection map

Comment: Yes, that is true.